# Angular dynamic reactive formControl which represents array value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a dynamic form with several controls which were created with new `FormControl(...)`,
one of the controls represents an array as a value.
What i'm trying to do is:

- change the control value with `control.setValue([...])`
- as soon as i change the control value, i need to check the `pristine` property of the form which contains the control
- but the `pristine` property is not changed

I know that i can use FormArray as the control and it should work, but i need to make it work with exactly FormControl.

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: setValue not change the pristine state, see a fool stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ctfalh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to valueChanges of the form

```
form.valuechanges().subscribe(res => {
    //form value changed
})
```

this will be called whenany of the controls value is changed

Answer (score 0):

Call `control.markAsDirty()` to mark it as dirty, ie. set `pristine` to false.

To also trigger a `valueChanges` event on it when setting value:

```
control.setValue([...], { emitEvent:true });
control.markAsDirty();
```